# For an instant message program, should your messages sent be left or right side?

Tags: usability, layout

For many IM programs, especially text apps for phones, you can see a conversation with a specific person. To quickly distinguish between messages sent and received, they are pushed to each side, like in this example.

[image: IM example]

I want to use this for what i'm making. I showed it to someone and found out we didn't agree on which messages should be left and which should be right.

I'm wondering which way I should put it now. which one is better, more used, and/or more intuitive

Answer (score 0):

### Left-to-right (LTR)

My instinct says that for a LTR directional reader the received messages should be on the left. As the recipients messages should have more prominence over your own, putting them on the left means your eye is drawn to them. Also and more importantly they are easier to read as you span down the chat feed as they are left aligned, the natural text alignment to read text for LTR readers.

### Right-to-left (RTL)

For RTL readers, the opposite is true. i.e. recipients messages on the right side and right aligned text.

---

### Conclusion

Alter the UI based on LTR/RTL reading settings.